# Assigning a shortcut to send keyboard input, in Plasma 5.18 - never works,

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, kde, plasma-5

I want to send a keyboard / character (to the active window).

This never did what I intended. No input was sent to any application (qt/gtk/console).

**steps (as per [the documentation](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/kcontrol/khotkeys/khotkeys.pdf)) **

- open "custom shortcuts"
- create new > global shortcut > keyboard input
- assign a shortcut key
- write the characters to be sent
- Apply / ok.

**background:**

- Assigning shortcuts to specific functions in specific apps -> work
- I created [this bug report at bugs.kde.org](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=427509)
- Kubuntu 20.04
- Plasma 5.18
- EN+HE keyboard layouts

**Semi-successful workaround using xdotool:**

- install xdtool
- create a script that sends intended keystrokes  (`xdotool type text`)
- in Plasma, create a custom COMMAND (instead of keyboard input)
- This sometime works, usually not, unknown factors.
- xdotool works by itself, i.e. from console or script, e.g. "sleep 10 ; xdotool type stuff" then switch window.
- At best, pressing the key-combo did "awkward" things, like moving windows around, or sending tab key to the active window.

I'm at loss.

I'm looking either for a solution, a workaround, or explanation.

**BTW: Is it mandatory to restart after every change in custom keys?**

Answer (score 1):

There's a systemic bug there.
I have 2 workarounds, using xdotool

1. install xdotool (`apt install xdotool`).
2. Create a **custom shortcut** with the script as action (New > Global Shortcut > Command/URL; Trigger: (your key combo)

### Workaround #1 - sleep

Add a `sleep` command before calling xdotool:

```
sleep 0.6
xdotool type "¯\\_(ツ)_/¯"
```

### Woraround #2

Release the shortcut keys before calling xdotool:

```
xdotool keyup Super+n
xdotool type "¯\\_(ツ)_/¯"
```

### notes:

- in my case, the script can be called by multiple shortcut keys. So I call `xdotool keyup` multiple time, for each key-combo.
- use *double quotes*. Don't ask me why. Not required for a single key.
- Escape the single backslash, i.e.  `"¯\\_(ツ)_/¯"`
- The reason for the workarounds, is that the key combo is using the meta key. If the meta key is pressed **while** the unicode code is sent to the current app, then Plasma is sending garbage to the current app / to the window management. With a small delay, it doesn't happen.
- xdotool sends it to the currently active window by default.
- This is obviously an ugly and fragile hack, NOT a rock solid feature.
- There are numerous KDE bugs around this feature, one of them is about reusing old shortcuts. If it doesn't work immediately, I recommend logout / restart.